# how can I copy custom exif fields from one image to another with exiftool?

Tags: metadata, exiftool

I am trying to copy all metadata from one image to another, including custom exif fields (in this case absolute and relative altitudes present in images from my DJI drone) using the command:

```
exiftool -tagsfromfile orig.jpg -all:all new.jpg
```

however only the standard tags are copied:

```
exiftool -s orig.jpg | grep -i alt

> GPSAltitudeRef                  : Above Sea Level
> AbsoluteAltitude                : -10.68
> RelativeAltitude                : +60.90
> GPSAltitude                     : 60.9 m Above Sea Level


exiftool -s new.jpg | grep -i alt

> GPSAltitudeRef                  : Above Sea Level
> GPSAltitude                     : 60.9 m Above Sea Level
```

Is there any way to copy all the tags across automatically, or do I have to add them one at a time?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:
`exiftool -tagsfromfile orig.jpg -exif new.jpg`

*Edit:*  See the last few paragraphs of [Exiftool FAQ #9](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/faq.html#Q9).  A similar command is mentioned there but unfortunately was inaccurate until today.

Comment: perfect - once I figured out which group the custom tags were in (using "exiftool -s -g orig.jpg" - in this case the xmp group), I fixed it using -xmp instead of -exif from your example.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

As you say, `AbsoluteAltitude` and `RelativeAltitude` do not appear to be defined tags. `exiftool` cannot copy them if it does not know how they are defined. In Phil Harvey's (author of exiftool) answer in [this discussion at exiftool's forum](http://130.15.24.88/exiftool/forum/index.php?topic=6413.0), you must create a user-defined tag in order for `exiftool` to write it.

Please see the [`exiftool` sample config file](http://owl.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/config.html) for details and examples.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response - really useful to understand the flexibility offered using a custom config file.  Found the solution below this to be a simpler approach for a quick fix though.

Comment: That's a much better solution! I would much rather just have a simple command line than writing custom tags